# Facebook Groups: Approve/Disapprove all pending posts

Tags: facebook-groups

I own a 35000+ member group and I have around 1000 publications to approve/disapprove daily. I would like to know if there is any way that I can select multiple ones and then apply the same action for it.

This way I could make it really faster.